# Зачем в патерне проектирования Wrapper передавать в конструктор обьект класса его расширяющего?

Tags: java

Давно известный шаблон проектирования `Wraper` или `Decorator`

Вот [пример](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) на `java` из википедии

```
abstract class WindowDecorator extend Window {
protected Window windowToBeDecorated; // the Window being decorated

public WindowDecorator (Window windowToBeDecorated) {
    this.windowToBeDecorated = windowToBeDecorated;
}
public void draw() {
    windowToBeDecorated.draw(); //Delegation
}
public String getDescription() {
    return windowToBeDecorated.getDescription(); //Delegation
}
}
```

Так вот я не совсем пойму зачем в обертку передавать обьект класса от которого наследуешся?

При наследовании мы и так получаем все тоже самое и можем на прямую вызывать...

Comment: Я здесь вижу имплементацию интерфейса и никакого наследования

Comment: @pavlofff сорри, исправил. Но ведь суть вопроса от этого не поменялась

Comment: потому что внутрь может быть передан любой наследник

Comment: теперь в примере на который вы ссылаетесь нет никакого наследования, а есть имплементация интерфейса, возможно следует поправить и википедию или более внимательно прочитать, что же там все же написано :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть такой имплементации декоратора в том, что она добавляет функциональность к любому **уже существующему** объекту.

Если объект под вашим контролем, тогда вы можете и правда унаследоваться от него и добавить/поменять нужную функциональность самостоятельно. Но если объект создаётся/настраивается/конфигурируется не вами или не под вашим контролем, то вы не сможете самостоятельно сделать дубликат, и вам придётся проксировать вызовы, как это и делается в упомянутом вами паттерне.

Answer (score 2):

Основное отличие шаблона `декоратор` от наследования в том, что функциональность расширяется динамически и на уровне объектов, а не классов, как при наследовании. Это может быть полезно, например - когда существует большое количество комбинаций функциональности, которое при обычном наследовании потребует создание огромного количества подтипов или, например - когда функциональность должна добавляться для некоторых объектов, а не для всего типа(класса) или если нет возможности изменить реализацию какого-то класса.

> Так вот я не совсем пойму зачем в обертку передавать обьект класса от
>   которого наследуешся?

Объект, который декорирует ваш «первоначальный» объект, не должен изменять его тип, иначе мы уже не сможем говорить о расширении свойств того же объекта.

Comment: Ага, произвольная комбинируемость тоже важна.